# Text overlapping issue

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a a web chat and I am trying to set up my message timestamp to be a little more up.. meaning that the margins are overlapping. I am not sure how to set my text div to be wide enough so the timestamp doesn't overlap with actual message text.

```css
.message-box {
  background-color: #7facd3;
  align-self: flex-start;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: 3px 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.message-text {
  margin-top: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: fit-content;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.timestamp-div {
  display: block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: -11px 0 0 0;
  width: min-content;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class='message-box'>
  <span class='username'>Aleks</span>
  <div class='message-text'>Message.</div>
  <div class='timestamp-div'>14:56</div>
</div>
```

Current situation:

[image: Current situation.]

Comment: A potential design solution is to put the timestamp at the top-right instead of at the bottom

Comment: Try to remove -11px in your .timestamp-div margin?

Comment: This is really a design dilemma, not coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-right: -30px;` to timestamp-div and `padding-right: 35px` to message-box.

```
    .message-box {
        background-color: #7facd3;
        align-self: flex-start;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: min-content;
        max-width: 85%;
        margin: 3px 10px 0 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        padding-right: 35px;
    }

    .message-text {
        margin-top: 4px;
        text-align: left;
        width: fit-content;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

    .timestamp-div {
        display: block;
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin: -11px 0 0 0;
        width: min-content;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-right: -30px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing! Thank you kind stranger!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `margin` from your `.timestamp-div` and the time will be shown below the text (You can also just remove the `-11px`)

Here's your code:

```css
.message-box {
  background-color: #7facd3;
  align-self: flex-start;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: 3px 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.message-text {
  margin-top: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: fit-content;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.timestamp-div {
  display: block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: min-content;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class='message-box'>
  <span class='username'>Aleks</span>
  <div class='message-text'>Message.</div>
  <div class='timestamp-div'>14:56</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If, for whatever reason, they want to keep the negative margin, a small amount of top padding (1.25em or so) also does the trick.

Comment: @MajorProductions Yes, that would be a solution too. But i think it would look cleaner by just removing the margin instead of using a negative margin + padding